# Why doesn't Tomcat 6 find my styles.css

Tags: css, tomcat

Trying to determine where/how to place style sheets in web app
deployed to Tomcat 6 so that the styles.css can be resolved.
I've tried every thing I can think of without success.

I did these tests to ferret out were to put the file but
little has been successful.

```
1.) put css in-line with style attribute to verify text display green. 
    <div id="xxx" style="color:green;">  This worked.
    Then I removed the attribute and
2.) moved it into a in-file <style></style> stmt in the jsp.  This also worked. 
    I copied the css stmt into styles.css and disabled the in-line stmt in the jsp.
3.) added <link></link> stmts to file.  I tried several path refs to the file.
    And I put the file in several different directory locations to see where
    it would get resolved. (none were found)
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">

Using FireBug (css tab) I see the follow information for these links
  * <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    this displays the src to index.html in the root dir

  * <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    this displays the msg 
        Apache Tomcat/6.0.13 - Error report
        HTTP Status 404
        The requested resource () is not available.

  * <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">      
    this displays
        Failed to load source for: http://192.168.5.24:9191/css/clStyles.css
```

The contextPath is /microblog
And basepath is http://192.168.5.24:9191/microblog

Here is the test code I am using.

I am using Spring 3.  I have a simple JSP

-- test.jsp --

```
    <%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
    %>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base href="<%=basePath%>">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
        <style> 
            #Yxxx {color:green;}
        </style>

      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="xxx">
            <h2>Test  <%=path%>  <%=basePath%></h2>
        </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

I've placed the styles.css file at many directory locations to see
where it might get resolved but none appear to be found.

In Tomcat 6 the deployed exploded web app directory structure

```
    webapps/microblog
    webapps/microblog/styles.css
    webapps/microblog/index.html
    webapps/microblog/css/styles.css
    webapps/microblog/WEB-INF/css/styles.css
    webapps/microblog/WEB-INF/jsp/admintest/styles.css
    webapps/microblog/WEB-INF/jsp/admintest/test.jsp
```

So how to get Tomcat 6 to resolve .css files?

Answer (score 9):

Likely the relative CSS path is plain wrong. Make it domain-relative instead of path-relative. Prepend it with the context path (which is `/microblog` in your case):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css">
```

Note that resources in `/WEB-INF` are not publicitly accessible. They're only accessible by `RequestDispatcher` in servlets or by `<jsp:include>` in JSPs. Put them outside `/WEB-INF`.

If it still doesn't work, then likely a servlet or filter which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/` or `/*` is not doing its job properly.

Comment: Thank you both. This information it was helpful.

With your recommended changes and one change to my 
<url-pattern>, (changing the pattern from / to
*.html) this is working.

I would like to understand why the url-pattern change enabled
Tomcat to resolve the refs.  Can any one point me
to an article or provide an explanation.   

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you map a servlet on `/` then you're basically overriding servletcontainer's own default servlet which is used for all requests which doesn't match URL pattern of all other declared servlets (for example, static resources like images, CSS, JS, etc files). In case of Tomcat, check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

Answer (score 6):

Probably it's quite late but I managed to resolve this in a different way.

I have a simple html file inside my WebContent and a css folder:

this was not working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

and neither this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

this IS working, but it's ugly (and it's also giving me a warning in Eclipse):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myproject/css/styles.css">
```

so I found that also this one is working, and seems the best approach to me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
```

Comment: This is very good! The ${pageContext.request.contextPath} causes some random compiling errors which drove me nuts... thanks!

Comment: awesome simple html page i am using it gives exact path

Answer (score 3):

none of the following will work deploying to  http://192.168.5.24:9191/microblog

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

This one points to  http://192.168.5.24:9191/styles.css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

This one points to  http://192.168.5.24:9191/css/styles.css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

This one points to  http://192.168.5.24:9191/css/styles.css

You need to prefix the context path :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css">
```

or the full path :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=basePath%>/styles.css">
```

The resources under /WEB-INF should be removed as they're not available for external requests

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using the HTML [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) so that you don't need to type ${pageContext.request.contextPath} all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I solved it by simply typing a space anywhere in the css file and saving it. The path should just be "css/style.css". It seems to me that sometimes Tomcat wouldn't recognize your file immediately if that file (or the path to the file) is changed such as renamed or relocated. The only way I find to make Tomcat "realize" this change is to make some change in the file and save it, and redeploying or refreshing wouldn't help if this hasn't been done.